# Increase the speed of Maven release prepare and perform task?

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, pom.xml

I've found some ways to increase the speed of our standard maven builds such as only building modules that have changed and utilising parallel builds. For the task:

`clean release:prepare release:perform`

It takes a while and I'd like to speed up. It seems the parallel builds doesn't work I get an error. Any suggestions on how to speed up? I assume I could skip tests and they're already being done on the builds on the dev branch before it's merged with master?

The error I get when running parallel builds is:

```
[ERROR] NullPointerException
[ERROR] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This seems to be the only error I get - not sure why?

Comment: What problems did you experience with parallel build?

Comment: Same as @JFMeier asking... ` It seems the parallel builds doesn't work I get an error.` What errors? Show log file etc.?

Comment: Have edited the main post to show the error

Comment: Please run your build with `-X` flag so that you get the whole stacktrace (and publish it here).